# Custom validator for reactive forms angular

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

I have created like this validator for reactive form, all working but I think I used so many statements, can somebody help me to make proper validation

Here is my validator

```
export function validateIfOneIsRequired(): ValidatorFn {
  return function validateIfOneIsRequired(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    const startTime = formGroup.controls.startTime.value;
    const endTime = formGroup.controls.endTime.value;
    if (startTime === '' && endTime === '') {
      return null;
    }
    if (startTime && endTime) {
      return null;
    }

    if (!startTime && endTime) {
      return { startTimeIsRequired: OperationalTime.startTimeIsRequired };
    }

    if (startTime && !endTime) {
      return { endTimeIsRequired: OperationalTime.endTimeIsRequired };
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and elaborate what this code exactly is supposed to do, and how it is used in context.

Comment: if you look the code you will see that this is validator for reactive forms? it should validate if one of fields is required